# Safe to reset a MediaPlayer in preparing state?

Tags: android

I'm writing an audio player using MediaPlayer that allows the user to skip the actual tune. A skip request might occur at any time, including between a call to MediaPlayer.prepareAsync and the upcoming onPrepared callback. The doc says:

*It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined.*

Does that include calls to reset, or even to release? Because if it so, then I would either have to wait for the onPrepared callback to reuse the MediaPlayer or allocate a brand new MediaPlayer if I don't want to wait and release the obsolete one on the onPrepared callback, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion i will follow the advice in the docs, i found several issues with player in different devices (in some devices is not stable at all reusing the same player).

I think a good option is to have to players allocated, and switch between them when user skips a tune, then you wait for the original player to arrive to prepared state and then you reset it safely.

Comment: I've read somewhere that MediaPlayer instances are quite resources-heavy and that we should never rely on more than two. I already use two instances: one for playing the actual tune, the other one to prepare (and play) the next one. So if MediaPlayer.release was at least valid at all times, then I could ensure that I always have no more than two MediaPlayer instances.

Comment: That is ok, with two instances you can wait for the one in preparing state to change to prepared state before releasing it, while with the other you play the next tune.

Answer (score 5):

I also built a stream music player and struggled with the preparing state. The worse part of it was that there were some streams where prepare() hung forever downloading (buffering) data without ever calling onBufferUpdate. Calling release did nothing. So, the way I did it was calling reset() on the stuck MediaPlayer from anotherthread after 15 seconds despite the recommendations in the docs. This caused it to throw an exception and brought it to error state. After catching the exception I called release(). This seems to have solved the problem. I hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing an issue when MP "hangs" at preparing state too long (stream) and i'm trying to stop it using reset(). This causes MP to hang and thus my whole app freezes. Seems like there is no way to stop MP at preparing state. Im thinking on use prepare() wrapped in thread instead of prepareAsync(). Then i'll be able to kill that thread. As for now i did it in following way:

```
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(new String());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            android.util.Log.d(TAG,"actionCancel(): mp.setDataSource() exception");
            mp.reset();
        }
```

and it works 4me.

Comment: In your code, if the exception is catched, it's because you were trying to set new data to your player. Then you reset your player... But finally you don't set your data to the player.

Comment: You just didn't get the trick cuz probably didn't read my post. I don't need to set any DataSource I just need to stop/reset MP at preparing state. And only after exception catch I could finally use reset safely.

Comment: The doc said, which i quote "It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined." Is there any side effect of using this way?