# MediaPlayer: which calls are allowed in 'preparing' state

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

This is a followup [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971914/safe-to-reset-a-mediaplayer-in-preparing-state). The [MediaPlayer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) are very specific about which calls can be made in which state, *except* for which calls are allowed in the 'preparing' state. And it says:

> the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined.

However, it fails to define which methods have side effects and thus result in undefined behavior! Of course in particular I'm interested if stop() or reset() can be called.

Why isn't the preparing state documented?