# Android prepareaync() Timeout

Tags: java, android, url, streaming, media-player

I have a mediaplayer that streams shoutcast stations. My problem is if the stream stops working for any reason the mediaplayer still trys to load it with prepareaync and I have no way to stop it from loading.
I have tried creating a timer that cancels the progress screen and calls `finish()` but this still does not stop the prepareasync from loading.
I also tried doing a sort or url validation with geturlconnection but this does not seem to work either. Any ideas would be much appreciated...

Comment: To anyone with a similar problem I ended up using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971914/safe-to-reset-a-mediaplayer-in-preparing-state) to reset the media player. I also found that this only works on a actual device, the emulator does not behave the same as a device in this scenario. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180670/android-mediaplayer-is-preparing-too-long?rq=1) was very helpful also...